# ¿Cómo configurar access origin en cordova y node?

Tags: nodejs, cordova, access-control

les cuento, estoy realizando un app en Codrova con un servidor en Node, realizo las peticiones por ajax por lo que en mi servidor Node tengo que configurar el header Access-Origin, ahora, mi duda es:

Solo quiero que el servidor sea accesible desde mi App Codrova, leí por ahí sobre las Whitelist (que se configuran en la app) y entendí perfectamente, pero en el servidor qué tengo que hacer para bloquear el resto del las peticiones?

Agradezco si alguien sabe algo sobre esto y me puede proporcionar información.

Answer (score 1):

[`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) es una herramienta de la especificación `HTTP` la cual nos permite por medio de un encabezado seteado desde el servidor en cada respuesta, el permiso para acceder a recursos de otro dominio; a esto último se le conoce como **dominio cruzado**, que es simplemente la acción de acceder a recursos en un dominio distinto en donde se generó el documento. La política de seguridad que maneja esto se conoce como [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) o *restricción de mismo origen*.

La manera de especificar *qué dominios tienen permiso de consumir recursos* es mediante la cabecera [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin), la cual acepta un dirección URI.

En [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs), específicamente, en el archiconocido [express](/questions/tagged/express), puedes especificar una *white list* de los sitios que deberían tener acceso al recurso:

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors({
  origin: whitelist,
));
```

Donde `whitelist` es un array con los sitios permitidos:

```
const whitelist = [
  'https://domain1.com',
  'https://domain2.org',
  'http://insecuredomain.net',
  // etc.
];
```

Si entra una petición de **un dominio que no está en la lista blanca**, será rechazada. Puedes también especificar una función para retornar una respuesta personalizada en caso el dominio no esté en lista blanca:

```
origin: function (origin, callback) {
  if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
    callback(null, true);
  } else {
    callback(new Error('No tienes permiso para consumir este recurso'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Una excelente respuesta, ahora, como en realidad quiero acceder desde una app de Cordova, la cual no sería un dominio en sí, qué le tendría que pasar a Cors en Node para que le permita acceder?

No estoy seguro si me explico